# Create a copy of .EXE but replacing name and GUID

Tags: c#

I have this one program that is called, for example, "Niop" and I need to change all traces of the word "Niop" to "Juop" programmatically. So the way I've been going about this is opening it in Visual Studio, doing Ctrl-F and replacing all the strings from "Niop" to "Juop" and then going to properties and changing the GUID manually and any other traces of "Niop".

I tried converting the exe into base64 and replacing all "TmlvcA" (Niop) with "SnVvcA" (Juop) but then when I opened the program, it still was called "Niop.exe" and all the properties still said "Niop".

I'm trying to somehow get into the exe and change these programmatically.

```
    private void RetoneForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        num1 = File.ReadAllText("retone.txt"); //EXE in Base64

        name = Regex.Match(num1, @"HRvbmkA(.*?)AYWRkX").Groups[1].Value + "="; //Find "Niop"
        guid = Regex.Match(num1, @"ApAQAk(.*?)AAAMAQ").Groups[1].Value; //Find GUID

        txtName.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(name));
        txtGUID.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(guid));
    }

    private void bRetone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name2 = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txtName.Text)).Trim('=');
        string guid2 = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txtGUID.Text));

        string num2 = Regex.Replace(num1, name.Trim('='), name2); //replace "Niop" with "Juop"
               num2 = Regex.Replace(num2, guid, guid2); //replace GUID

        Clipboard.SetText(num2); //new Base64
    }
```

I also dragged the EXE into a Hex editor and tried replacing the values that way and this did change all traces of "Niop" but some characters got changed to little squares.

I know I can't use base64 to do this, any ideas on how I could achieve this?

Comment: replacing base64 values doesn't make sense. " Niop"  (with a space at the beginning) will not result with something with "TmlvcA". But as long as it's a one shot, it's quicker doing it manuallly.

Comment: If the byte sequence Niop happens to appear as content other than static text data in the executable you will break it in a way that would only manifest itself at runtime.

Comment: Yeah I realized this once I compiled it.

Comment: `So the way I've been going about this is opening it in Visual Studio, doing Ctrl-F and replacing all the strings from "Niop" to "Juop" and then going to properties and changing the GUID manually and any other traces of "Niop".` Keep on that approach.

Comment: The only reason I needed to do this is because I need to rename this multiple times. I need to be able to change it from "Juop" to "Kepo" to "Jimo" to "Hede", etc.

Comment: So automate that process using grep etc.